# How to apply gradient descent onto a 3-particle system and calculate its energy

Tags: python, matplotlib, gradient-descent

I'm running into an overflow problem with my code.

I'm supposed to write Python code to apply gradient descent onto a 3 particle system and calculate its energy.

For reference, the energy of the system (setting all the physical constants to 1 for simplicity) is given by

```
$$
E(\vec{x}_1, \vec{x}_2, \dots, \vec{x}_N)=\overbrace{\sum_i ||\vec{x}_i||^2}^{\text{Harmonic potential}}+\overbrace{\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=i+1}^N\frac{1}{||\vec{x}_i-\vec{x}_j||}}^{\text{Coulomb repulsion}}
$$
```

where `$\vec{x}_i$` is the vector containing the position of particle `$i$, $\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=i+1}^N$` is the sum over all possible pairs of different particles and `$||\vec{x}||=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$` is the Euclidean norm.

This is my code. I'm pretty sure `gradient_energy` is good and that the problem is in `gradient_descent`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gradient_energy(configuration):
    N = configuration.shape[0]
    gradient = np.zeros_like(configuration, dtype=np.float64)

    h_pot_gradient = 2 * configuration
    gradient -= h_pot_gradient

    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i + 1, N):
            r_ij = configuration[i] - configuration[j]
            d = np.linalg.norm(r_ij)
            c_rep_gradient = r_ij / (d ** 3)
            gradient[i] += c_rep_gradient
            gradient[j] -= c_rep_gradient

    return gradient

def gradient_descent(configuration, gamma, T, epsilon):
    for i in range(T):
        gradient = gradient_energy(configuration).astype(np.float64) #again, there was a problem with the types, so the solution ChatGPT gave is the .astype(np.flpat64) part
        frobenius_norm = np.linalg.norm(gradient)
        if frobenius_norm < epsilon:
            break
        configuration -= gamma * gradient
    return configuration

def get_energy(configuration):
    N = configuration.shape[0]
    h_pot = np.sum(np.linalg.norm(configuration, axis=1) ** 2)
    c_rep = 0.0
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i + 1, N):
            d = np.linalg.norm(configuration[i] - configuration[j])
            c_rep += 1 / d

    E = h_pot + c_rep
    return E

gamma = 0.1
T = 1000
epsilon = 1e-6
initial_config = np.array([[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]], dtype=np.float64)
final_config = gradient_descent(initial_config, gamma, T, epsilon)

energy_final = get_energy(final_config)
print("Energy of the obtained configuration is ", energy_final)

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.scatter(final_config[:, 0], final_config[:, 1], s=50)
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.title("Configuration after Gradient Descent")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

`gradient_energy` gives me the gradient of the energy matrix.
`h_pot` and `c_rep` are the Harmonic and Coulomb energies.
`Gamma` is the learning rate, `T` is the iterations, `epsilon` is the convergence threshold.

Another problem I get is when I want to plot, I only get 3 points (although that might be because already at the third iteration I have an overflow but I'm not sure).

Comment: `Another problem i get is when i want to plot, i only get 3 points` There are only 3 particles at the beginning, no? Why would you get more or less points?

Comment: Have you tried dropping your learning rate?

Comment: @rsenne I did, however it doesn't really solve it, i still get immense energies, and the learning rate should be 0.1 (its given that way in the exercise)

Comment: @NickODell i thought i would plot all gradient descent steps, however ineed i only wrote code to plot the final configuration

Comment: Solved it, it was an extra -  sign...

Comment: Do you mind to post your answer? That would be helpful to the community. Cheers